# How to mock Internal class in Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, justmock

```
//Claim class Developed in solution ABC
class Claim
{
    public Claim(string s)
    {
        // progreamm.....
    }
}

//Test Case needs to write in Solution XYZ
[TestClass]
public class ClaimTest
{
    public void myconstructor()
    {
        //Now Question is how to access class Claim here?
    }
}

//Now Question is how to access class Claim constructor in myconstructor //function.

//Hope you get what i need to access using Just Mock in telerik
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to unit test internal classes; only public APIs. If you can't test `Claim` properly via the public classes that use it, then there's a problem with your code design.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is add the [InternalsVisibleTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to the assembly that contains the internal class. It is explained in the [JustMock documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/basic-usage-mock-internal-types-via-proxy.html).

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Telerik.JustMock, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100098b1434e598c6" +
"56b22eb59000b0bf73310cb8488a6b63db1d35457f2f939f927414921a769821f371c31a8c1d4b" +
"73f8e934e2a0769de4d874e0a517d3d7b9c36cd0ffcea2142f60974c6eb00801de4543ef7e93f7" +
"9687b040d967bb6bd55ca093711b013967a096d524a9cadf94e3b748ebdae7947ea6de6622eabf" +
"6548448e")]
```

After that, rebuild the assembly and then you can use the internal types in the test assembly, just as if they were public types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Ffakingnonpublicobjects.htm) for faking internal types.
So in your test, you will use:

```
var fakeInternal = Assembly.Load("ABC").GetType("ABC.Claim");
var fake = Isolate.NonPublic.Fake.Instance(fakeInternal);
```

And from this point, you can use the `Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled` API for setting the method behavior.

And use the `Isolate.Invoke.Method` API to invoke the relevant methods.